# Degeneracy of eigenvalues of tensor products of Pauli matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products

If I consider a finite tensor product of Pauli matrices, say $P = P_1\otimes P_2\otimes ... \otimes P_n$, then I can observe that

$$P^2 = I$$

This implies that the eigenvalues of $P$ are $\pm 1$. If however I am given that $P_i\neq I$ i.e. I only consider products of $\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z$, how can I show that there exist an equal number of $+1$ eigenvectors and $-1$ eigenvectors?

Comment: Each $P_i$ is similar to $-P_i$. Use this to show that $P$ is similar to $-P$.

Comment: That's neat, thank you!